# Will sudo from a Standard User account affect my admin account?

Tags: macos, terminal, admin, sudo

Say I have two user accounts on my computer. One admin, one standard user. If I then use sudo and other things which need admin rights from my Standard user account, install a lot of different packages and just experiment a lot with that user account, and then decide to delete the account at some point, will there be any effects for my admin user account later? is i possible that this will change certain files in my admin account etc.?

Comment: Apart from being off-topic (it would fit better on the sister site http://superuser.com), I'm not sure this question is answerable. The commands you run will affect whatever you ask them to affect; `sudo do_something` just means "run `do_something` as another (normally admin) user". If you say `sudo passwd`, for instance, you change the admin's password, so that admin account would most definitely have changed permanently. And if you install a package, it will generally be global to the whole system, not one user account (which is why you need admin permission to do it in the first place).

Comment: sorry for the offtopic, i ll close this then. is it possible to install things only locally then? I would prefer this, but seem to run into sudo requests *all the time*, so I'm wondering whether it even made sense that I created a new (standard) user account for this..